# Unable to open parts of Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Recently, and not seemingly on account of any change I made, I can now no longer properly load parts of a project in VSU2010. See below for the error I get when opening a test in Test List Editor:

[image]

However if I open the same one from the Solution Explorer, I get:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are referencing an assembly which in turn referencing an old version of `LoadTestPackage`

You can  use  FuseLogVw in order to find who is loading the old assemblies, you can define a path for the log, and run your solution.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Nota : Clean Debug and Release folders in your solution, then remove and add LoadTestPackage reference

Comment: Hi Aghilas Yakoub - I have tried to launch various FuseLogVW exe's I found in both Program Files and PF (x86), as an escalated process, but cannot see a single failed assembly binds. Not even after initating the above error message, and clicking refresh. Also, as eluded to in your reply, just wanted to make sure you were aware that only I have been working on this project. Also, which Debug and Release folder should I be clearing?

Comment: right click on your solution et select Clean Solution in order to clean your directories Bin/Debug or release

Comment: Hi Candie - The clean apparently completed successfully. How do I remove and add the LoadTestPackage reference?